# Chemical potential in superfluids and superconductors

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, chemical-potential, superfluidity

It's been known for a long time, probably since the formulation of Landau's two-fluid model of superfluid 4He, that superfluids accelerate in response to gradients in the chemical potential (per unit mass):

$\dot{\vec{v}}_s = -\vec{\nabla} \mu = \frac{h}{m}\frac{d}{dt}\vec{\nabla}\phi$

where $\vec{\nabla}\phi$ refers to a gradient is the superfluid phase. What is the rationale behind this equation? It seems like originally, in superfluid 4He, Landau just postulated that it was correct (probably based on some experimental observations), but it is also correct for superconductors. Is there an intuitive way to understand this simple equation?

Comment: The chemical potential is a junk term. When we consider the internal energy as a function of S, V and N the chemical potential is just a junk term involving the magnetic field, electric field etc. and most typically the chemical composition

Answer (score 1):

This basic equation of the Landau's two-fluid model is the famous "Josephson relation", as discussed in the seminal 1966 paper of P.W. Anderson on the flow of superfluid helium:

P. W. ANDERSON
Considerations on the Flow of Superfluid Helium
Rev. Mod. Phys. 38, 298 – Published 1 April 1966

In a superfluid the Josephson relation is equation (14) here (I suggest you to read section I-A and I-E): 
 https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.5629

There is also a formulation of your equation in General Relativity, where the connection with the Josephson relation is even more clear (because using 4-vector formalism you have to "group together" the chemical potential and the superfluid velocity into a unique entity): see for example equation (30) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.03140

Comment: thanks, those references look useful. I'll try to go through them this weekend.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit the post with the abstracts.